# How to put a battery and battery charger parallel in a circuit

Tags: battery-charging, parallel, charging, output

I am making a speaker that runs at 3-5.5 RMS and I need a battery to supply power to it and so I got a house phone battery pack with a diode now I need a way to charge this so when it is charging that the load will still go in the amp here is what I thought please feedback will be amazing.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "making a speaker"? Do you mean an amplifier? If so, what is the voltage range allowed for the power input of the amplifier? When you said "3-5.5 RMS" did you mean 3 to 5.5 volts?

Comment: IF the charger is suitable for charging the battery in isolation then it will probably work OK as shown. The diode is probably not needed. | Hand drawn diagrams are acceptable but a tidier one (use a ruler etc or cause the system to draw straight lines if electronically formed) or (best) use the system provided schematic drawing tool.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, this question is poorly worded, and you may find that to cause you a bit of trouble. Moving on, then.

Your charger output looks like it most likely is not designed for the battery you are using. You didn't exactly tell us much about the battery, or your application.

Assuming that 4.5 volts is not dangerous for the battery - and it might be - one of the neat things about dc is that load sharing is fairly automatic. Physics is on your side.

As long as the battery is in good health, and not going to explode because of the charger you put on it, the system will draw proportionally from the battery and the charger, depending on their actual terminal voltages and their actual output impedance. Typically, a well designed charger has a lower output impedance and a higher voltage than the battery it is attached to, and thus will assume most of the load being drawn.

A side effect of this, is that the charger will most likely put out as much as it can and get stuck so to speak. The battery will not only fail to charge, but likely will continue discharging to power the load.

This is where you come in. You have to design the system such that the battery will charge when its supposed to, and still maintain continuity of power to the load. Proper battery chargers with current monitoring functions and state of charge estimation are great little projects to learn on.

Comment: Note, also, that battery operated devices typically decide when to stop the charge, and sometimes throttle it. In that case, the charger is simply a dc output with the correct voltage and sufficient ampacity to meet the needs of the device.

Comment: Hey i'm sorry that it was such a poorly asked question. The home phone li-ion battery charges safely on 4.5 volts thank you for your input and the battery as an micro chip that controls discharge and recharge so it doesn't go under or over

Comment: Well it sounds like your power supply is just about all set then. Stay safe, and ask questions.